# python giving error in extracting a file from the file

Tags: python, tar

Python code:

```
import tarfile,os
import sys
def extract_system_report (tar_file_path):
    extract_path = ""
    tar = tarfile.open(sys.argv[1])
    for member in tar.getmembers():
        print ("member_name is: ")
        print (member.name)
        tar.extract(member.name, "./crachinfo/")
extract_system_report(sys.argv[1])
```

while extracting the file getting below error:

```
>> python tar_read.py /nobackup/deepakhe/POLARIS_POJECT_09102019/hackathon_2021/a.tar.gz 

member_name is: 
/bootflash/.prst_sync/reload_info

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tar_read.py", line 38, in <module>
    extract_system_report(sys.argv[1])
  File "tar_read.py", line 10, in extract_system_report
    tar.extract(member.name, "./crachinfo/")
  File "/auto/pysw/cel8x/python64/3.6.10/lib/python3.6/tarfile.py", line 2052, in extract
    numeric_owner=numeric_owner)
  File "/auto/pysw/cel8x/python64/3.6.10/lib/python3.6/tarfile.py", line 2114, in _extract_member
    os.makedirs(upperdirs)
  File "/auto/pysw/cel8x/python64/3.6.10/lib/python3.6/os.py", line 210, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, mode, exist_ok)
  File "/auto/pysw/cel8x/python64/3.6.10/lib/python3.6/os.py", line 220, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/bootflash'
```

I am specifying the folder to extract but still it seems trying to create a folder in the root directory. is this behavior expected? I can extract  this tar file fine in file manager. is there a way to handle this in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am specifying the folder to extract but still it seems trying to create a folder in the root directory. is this behavior expected?

Yes. The path provided is just a "current directory", it's not a "jail". The documentation even specifically warns about it:

> It is possible that files are created outside of path, e.g. members that have absolute filenames starting with `"/"` or filenames with two dots `".."`.

> I can extract this tar file fine in file manager. is there a way to handle this in python?

Use `extractfile` to get a pseudo-file handle on the contents of the archived file, then copy that wherever you want.

Comment: for file copy i am using: tar_ext=tar.extractfile(member)  content = tar_ext.read()
        print (extract_path)
        extract_file_fd = open("./example", "w+")
        extract_file_fd.write(content) now following is the error: ./BT_decode//crashinfo/tracelogs/IOSRP_R1-0.27588_8.20200825154215.bin.gz
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tar_read.py", line 38, in <module>
    extract_system_report(sys.argv[1])
  File "tar_read.py", line 31, in extract_system_report
    extract_file_fd.write(content)
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes

Comment: checked how to copy using python and seems we need to use shutil, and this need the source file path, which is not possible with tar_fd

Comment: The issue here is that the tar pseudo-file returns *binary* data, but you're opening the targer in *text* mode. You need to open the target file in binary mode as sell. `shutil` won't help you there as it will essentially do the same thing you do here, and will trigger the same error (`shutil.copyfile` takes two paths, but `shutil.copyfileobj` takes file-like objects so it'd work fine).

Comment: Thanks for the help.. opening the file with "wb+" and it is working fine.